# How can we demo Lost update, Uncommitted data, Unrepeatable data, Phantom on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm studying Database Management System and I have a project that I need to demo Lost update, Uncommitted data, Unrepeatable data, Phantom in a DMS I selected. I selected MySQL for my project. But after a couple of times trying to demonstrate I failed. This is a case I tried.

### This is transaction T1

`START TRANSACTION;`
`UPDATE roles SET roles.isAdmin = '0';`

`DO sleep(5);`

`ROLLBACK;`

### This is transaction T2

`START TRANSACTION;`

`SELECT * FROM roles WHERE 1;`

`COMMIT;`

Can you help me to figure out how can I demonstrate Lost update, Uncommitted data, Unrepeatable data, Phantom situation?

Comment: As I understand, those phenomena is caused by `dirty reads`.  IIRC - InnoDB stores don't support  `dirty reads`.

Answer (score 1):

The different problems are prevented at different isolation levels. So you need to first set an isolation level that allows a problem to happen before you can demonstrate it.

Here's a table that explains which isolation level allows which problem to occur (taken from [my post over at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119518/447489) which also briefly explains the problems the isolation levels are solving).

```
                 | Lost updates | Dirty Read | Non-Repeatable Read | Phantom Read
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Read Uncommitted | possible     | possible   | possible            | possible
Read Committed   | impossible   | impossible | possible            | possible
Repeatable Read  | impossible   | impossible | impossible          | possible
Serializable     | impossible   | impossible | impossible          | impossible
```

So, for the first example, the **lost update** problem, it would work like this:

```
session 1> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

session1 > select * from t;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

session 1> update t set a = 2;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0
```

The session is not yet committed, but in session 2 you can already see the value, when you set the isolation accordingly.

```
session2 > set session tx_isolation='read-uncommitted';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

session2 > start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

session2 > select * from t;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

session2 > update t set a=3 where a=2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

As you can see the `Changed` value for session 2 is `0`, because it read uncommitted values from session 1. When you commit both sessions now, no matter which one first, the values in column a will be `2`. The update statement of session 2 got lost.

*I think you get the idea, of how to demonstrate the problems. I got some work to do now. When you still have problems, I will update this post when I find the time.*

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I knew how to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

May I have another question that I demo isolation level `REPEATABLE READ`

### Transaction 1

```
start transaction;
select @parentName := S.parentalName
from `students` S
where S.studentID = '2';
do sleep(5);

set @parentName = CONCAT( @parentName, ' New ');

update `students`
set `parentalName` = @parentName
where `studentID` = '2';

commit;
```

### Transaction 2

```
start transaction;
select @parentName := S.parentalName
from `students` S
where S.studentID = '2';
do sleep(2);

set @parentName = CONCAT( @parentName, ' New_1 ');

update `students`
set `parentalName` = @parentName
where `studentID` = '2';

commit;
```

As I expect the result is

```
parentName New New_1
```

But my result is `parentName  New_1`. In this case Transaction 2 do not wait for Transaction 1 in select query. What should I explain in this case?